# How to customize PXI backplane settings via pyvisa?

Tags: python, triggers, hardware, labview, pyvisa

I want to modify settings of a [National Instruments PXI system](https://www.ni.com/de-de/innovations/white-papers/14/introduction-to-the-pxi-architecture.html) via [pyvisa](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/).
In particular, I want to programmatically route a trigger from bus 1 to bus 2 on the backplane.

There is [a documentation](https://www.ni.com/de-de/support/documentation/supplemental/18/using-pxi-timing-and-triggering-functionality.html) by National Instruments which explains the process via a Labview VI:

[image: labview customize pxi backplane trigger bus]

This basically tells me to

1. open a VISA session to the backplane
2. set src and dest trigger bus attributes
3. use map_trigger function

Step 1) works fine via pyvisa, I can open a communication with the backplane via `backplane = rm.open_resource('PXI0::2::BACKPLANE')`,  as described in the [resource names](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/1.8/names.html).

But after having opened a visa session to the backplane, I cannot find any of the described src trig bus and dest trig bus attributes here. There is only a bunch of attribute classes such as AttrVI_ATTR_RM_SESSION, which do not seem to contain any of the values I am interested in. But I guess I am misunderstanding something here.

Step 3) would be straightforward, as [this functionality is directly implemented in pyvisa](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/visalibrarybase.html#pyvisa.highlevel.VisaLibraryBase.map_trigger).

So the remaining question is: How can I modify the source trigger bus and destination trigger bus in a PXI backplane via pyvisa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the location of all required attributes:
pyvisa.constants lists all addresses of all possible attributes (for any interface).

To access a specific attribute, this can be implemented via the set_visa_attributes function:

```
import pyvisa
import pyvisa.constants

address = 'PXI0::2::BACKPLANE'
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
backplane = rm.open_resource(address)

src_bus = 2
dest_bus = 1
trigger = pyvisa.constants.VI_TRIG_TTL0  # i.e. PXI_Trig0

backplane.set_visa_attribute(pyvisa.constants.VI_ATTR_PXI_SRC_TRIG_BUS, src_bus)
backplane.set_visa_attribute(pyvisa.constants.VI_ATTR_PXI_DEST_TRIG_BUS, dest_bus)

# route trigger 0 from source bus to destination bus
backplane.visalib.map_trigger(backplane.session, trigger, trigger, pyvisa.constants.VI_NULL)
```